# Servicenow integration with Telegram messenger

Tags: telegram-bot, servicenow

Can anyone suggest me that,is it possible to create service now incident ticket using Telegram message.

Is there any documentation available to integrate servicenow bot in telegram for this purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Jup this should definitely be possible, I never tried writing a Telegram Bot but I'm sure you are able to handle REST/SOAP and that's how you would create an Incident. As of documentation for Service-Now you should look into [JSONv2](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=JSONv2_Web_Service) or [Table API](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Table_API#gsc.tab=0). Apparently as I said I don't have that much of a clue how Telegram Bots are working. I would suggest that you have a look at the [FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq).